# Composer autoloading files return Undefined variable

Tags: php, composer-php

Hello i have problem with composer when i autoload my config file.

In my **composer.json** i create

```
{
"require": {"monolog/monolog": "1.7.*@dev"},
"autoload":{
    "files": ["config/application.config.php"]
    }
}
```

I want to autoload my config file, and in my test.php file i put :

```
// Get composer autoloading
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

$logger = new Logger('my_logger');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__.'/data/logs/log.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$logger->pushHandler(new FirePHPHandler());

$logger->addInfo('test message');

// test
echo $config['logs_dir'];
```

My **application.config.php** file contain

```
/*
 * Data paths
 */
$config['cache_dir'] = 'data/cache';
$config['logs_dir']  = 'data/logs';
```

I get notice when i try to print value in my test.php calling 
echo $config['logs_dir']. File is succesful loaded by composer but notice what i get

**Notice: Undefined variable: $config in D:\xampp\htdocs\MCF3\index.php on line 18**

Comment: have you run `composer update` once you have update the composer.json?

Comment: yeah when do any changes i do update

Answer (score 7):

When Composer includes the file via `require` it is doing so within a function, and so doing:

```
$config['cache_dir'] = 'data/cache';
```

doesn't create a variable in the global scope. If you want to be able to read/write global variables you should explicitly use the `$GLOBALS` keyword.

```
$GLOBALS['config']['cache_dir'] = 'data/cache';
```